# customizing ngbAccordion

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-bootstrap

I am using NgbAccordion in one of my project and need to customise it text color property, but unable to do so. I have written the css but it is not affecting the accordion in any way. You can see my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgacu7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Also I came across [this](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1107) where users have mentioned that it is not possible to customise ngbAccordion, still I would like to know if anyone has figured this out. In case not, what other approach I can use, instead of bootstrap accordion, due to some project specific reasons am not allowed to use jquery and popper js in the project, that's why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the github issue link, which I have mentioned above, in the same thread I found this solution and it worked. Used the following css:

```
::ng-deep .card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

::ng-deep .card .card-header.active > a > span {
  color: #1d2124;
}
```

Have updated the stackblitz code also

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
 <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
          <div class="card title"><span class="steps">1</span>
            Step 1</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
 <span class="content">  
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
          aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
          sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
          craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
          occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
          labore sustainable VHS.
</span>
        </ng-template>
```

and in css

```
.title {
      background:#ccc;
       height:30px;
      color:#000;
    }
       .steps {
                  display: inline-block;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
                  width: 20px;
                  height: 20px;
                  border-radius: 50%;
                  border: 1px solid #000;
                  text-align: center;
                  margin-right: 10px;
                  color: #202A36;
            }
            .card {
              margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .content {
              color: #1b8cd3;
}
```

this is to give background color for heading, like that you can do with other styling properties